# Factors levels to columns names

Tags: r, r-factor

I have a data.frame as shown below:

```
Country Dealer       Q1                       Q4
Austria Dealer4      5_Very satisfied       5_Very satisfied
Austria Dealer7      5_Very satisfied       5_Very satisfied
Belgium Dealer24     5_Very satisfied       4_Satisfied
Denmark Dealer87     3_Partly satisfied     2_Dissatisfied
Denmark Dealer69     1_Very dissatisfied    4_Satisfied
```

With code can i use to have this.The questions are factors with 5 levels:

```
5_Very satisfied
4_Satisfied
3_Partly satisfied
2_Dissatisfied
1_Very dissatified


Contry  Dealer     QU   5_Very satisf  4_Satisf 3_Partly satisf 2_Dissatisfied  1_Very d
Austria Dealer4   Q1           1      0       0        0               0.            0
Austria Dealer7   Q1           1      0       0        0               0             0
Austria Dealer8   Q4           1      0.      0.       0.              0.            0
Austria Dealer9   Q4           1      0       0        0               0             0
Denmark Dealer87  Q1           0      0       1        0               0             0
Denmark Dealer69  Q1           0      0       0        0               1             0
Denmark Dealer51  Q4           0      0       0        1               0             0
```

Comment: Please share data with `dput` so ppl can easily copy-paste ur data.

Answer (score 0):

Try the [fastDummies::dummy_columns](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/fastDummies/versions/1.6.3/topics/dummy_columns). There is a great example on this link.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.